# When shell scripts echos "*", why it lists the files and directories?

Tags: linux, shell

I have written the following shell script to print "*" on the screen but when I execute the script, it lists all the files and directories in the current directory in which script is located. Can someone tell me why the script lists all the files and directories in the current directory?

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="*";
echo $TEST
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are missing some `""` around the `$TEST`.

Try `echo "$TEST"`.

Answer (score 2):

It prints all the files and folders because the shell, bash in your case, expands the * before passing it to the command.

The solution is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="*";
echo "$TEST"
```